# How do I determine whether linux process accounting (accton) is currently running?

Tags: linux, process-accounting

Is there any way to determine whether process accounting (accton) is running?  There is no process listed in the process table ("ps"), and I see nothing under "/etc" that I can call with "status" to get a status of accounting.

I'm running a custom build based on "Linux From Scratch", so while I understand that CentOS has "psacct", I don't have that available.

I could watch the log file and see if it's growing - not ideal, but if it's all I got, then it's all I got.  I'm hoping there's a better way.

Appreciate any info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can do like this. enable logging for your accton, an check the log file for update. like time stamp modification/lat access time/modify time ?

/sbin/accton /var/log/accto.log then the log will be created.

Then use some script to monitor your accto.log.  There are lot of log file monitoring scripts for nagios if you are interested.

Comment: Thanks - if I have to monitor the log file, then that's what I'll do.  I was hoping for a more accurate, or more "official" method.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question -- accton _filename_ would turn on accounting, regardless of whether it was running or not.